# How to use / translate "as well as" in next sentences?

Tags: word-requests

How to use "as well as" in these cases:

> We go to play football today **as well as** every sunday morning.
>
> I can see the road every bit **as well as** you can.‎
>
> The moon **as well as** the stars were shining down on them.‎
>
> **As well as** I recollect, he was about six feet tall.

Are they translated the same way or there should be used different translation of **as well as** - 以及 / 及其 / 而?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

as well as: 和；以及；如同；像...一樣；既...又...；

Depends on the context, you can choose a suitable one.

We go to play football today as well as every sunday morning.
和每周日上午一樣，我們今天也去踢足球。
我們今天和每周日上午一樣去踢足球。
We go to play football today and every sunday morning.
我們今天和每個星期天早上都去踢足球。

I can see the road every bit as well as you can.‎
我可以像你一樣看清楚路上的一切。

The moon as well as the stars were shining down on them.‎
月亮和星星一樣照著他們。
The moon and the stars were shining down on them.‎
月亮和星星都照著他們。

As well as I recollect, he was about six feet tall.
根據（如同）我的記憶，他身高約六英尺。
如同我記的一樣，他約六英尺高。
依我的記憶，他約六英尺高。
據我回憶，他約六英尺高。

Comment: I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

> We go to play football today as well as every sunday morning.

我们今天去踢球， 就像每个星期天早晨那样

Translated Style, OP gave a better one ....

> I can see the road every bit as well as you can.‎

我可以跟你一样看清这条路上的一切.

> The moon as well as the stars were shining down on them.‎

月亮、还有星星在他们头顶上照耀着。

> As well as I recollect, he was about six feet tall.

据我的记忆，他应该是6英尺高左右.

Comment: May be the first one should be "我们星期天早晨像往常一样去踢球."?

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko, Yeah, How come I ... :)

Answer (score 1):

there is a quite simple way to translate this word,just use 就像,it fit any status of the way you use 'as well as'